# typegraphql-prisma: Unable to infer GraphQL type from TypeScript reflection system

Tags: graph, prisma, typegraphql

I've got an application (`remix-run`) with prisma and mongodb. I would like to use `typescript-prisma` to generate graphql resolvers. In my `schema.prisma`, I have created a new generator

```
generator typegraphql {
  provider = "typegraphql-prisma"
  output = "path/to/generated/resolvers"
}
```

Then by executing the script `npx prisma generate`, I generate the prisma client and all graphql resolvers from my prisma schema. But every time I try to generate a (in-memory) graphql schema, I get the above error. This is the code I try to run:

```
import { resolvers } from "path/to/generated/resolvers"; // <-- this file fails with above error
...
const schema = await buildSchema({
  resolvers,
});
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "include": ["remix.env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2019", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "strict": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./app/*"]
    },
    "noEmit": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `npx prisma migrate dev` This command generates the Prisma client that will include the latest changes and also updated `typegraphql` resolvers. Then you will be able to import the resolvers.